# Get the hits of those days which have more hits than previous day

Tags: mysql

How to Get the hits of those days which have more hits than previous day.

```
Table structure

 Date      Hits

1-Mar-2013 36

2-Mar-2013 2

3-Mar-2013 99

4-Mar-2013 82

5-Mar-2013 34

6-Mar-2013 36

7-Mar-2013 56

8-Mar-2013 81

9-Mar-2013 8

10-Mar-2013 99

11-Mar-2013 12

12-Mar-2013 76

13-Mar-2013 75

14-Mar-2013 80

15-Mar-2013 69

16-Mar-2013 12

17-Mar-2013 3

18-Mar-2013 75

19-Mar-2013 7

20-Mar-2013 54

21-Mar-2013 82

22-Mar-2013 50

23-Mar-2013 29

24-Mar-2013 17

25-Mar-2013 78

26-Mar-2013 97

27-Mar-2013 76

28-Mar-2013 57

29-Mar-2013 28

30-Mar-2013 17
```

Can somebody suggest me a mysql queryy for doing this in one query itself. The Date column tells the date and the hits colum gives the hits on that day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT t2.*, t1.hits AS Previous_day_hits
FROM tab1 t1
INNER JOIN tab1 t2 ON  t2.DATE = date_add(t1.DATE, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  AND t2.hits > t1.hits;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c4ff/6)</kbd>

I added the column with Previous_day_hits for easier validation.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a [self join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Self-join). Basically you get two copies of the table and work out a rule to link them